# Loop through HTML and replace strings with javascript and Regex

Tags: javascript, html, anki

I have this HTML in [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net):

```html
<p>[!Quote] Title of callout 1<br>Content of callout 1</p>
<p>[!Quote] Title of callout 2<br>Content of callout 2</p>
<p>[!Quote] Title of callout 3<br>Content of callout 3</p>
```

And want it to look like this:

```html
<p><b>Title of callout 1</b><br>Content of callout 1</p>
<p><b>Title of callout 2</b><br>Content of callout 2</p>
<p><b>Title of callout 3</b><br>Content of callout 3</p>
```

So I want to remove `[!Quote]` and make `Title of callout` bold. I came up with this javascript code:

```js
var quoteRegex = /<p>\[!Quote].*(?=<br>)/g;
var title = /(?<=\[!Quote]\s).*(?=<br>)/g;
var back = document.getElementById('back'); // Backside of flashcard containing the paragraphs
var titleString = back.innerHTML.match(title);
back.innerHTML = back.innerHTML.replace(quoteRegex, '<b>' + titleString + '</b>');
```

But got stuck there, because `titleString` matches all titles and separates them with a comma,  hence causes something like this when I tried `back.innerHTML.replace`:

```js
<p><b>Title of callout 1, Title of callout 2, Title of callout 3</b><br>Content of callout 1</p>
```

Therefore I think I need to loop through the paragraphs so I can replace the titles one by one, but I have no idea how to get that done. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a capture group reference:

```js
const html = `<p>[!Quote] Title of callout 1<br>Content of callout 1</p>
<p>[!Quote] Title of callout 2<br>Content of callout 2</p>
<p>[!Quote] Title of callout 3<br>Content of callout 3</p>`;

$div.innerHTML = html.replace(/\[\!Quote\]\s*(.*?)<br>/g, '<b>$1</b><br>');
```

```html
<div id="$div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about capturing group references.

Answer (score 1):

There's an another approach with regex. Match `[!Quote]` and replace it instead of lookbehind.

```
const regex = /(?<quote>\[!Quote]\s)(?<title>.*)(?=<br>)/g;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('(?<quote>\\[!Quote]\\s)(?<title>.*)(?=<br>)', 'g')

const back = document.getElementById('back');
const subst = `<b>${title}</b>`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
back.innerHTML = = back.innerHTML.replace(regex, subst);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't work initially, got it working like this: `var extraRegex = /(?<quote>\[!Quote]\s)(?<title>.*)(?=<br>)/g;`; `back = document.getElementById('back');`; `back.innerHTML = back.innerHTML.replace(extraRegex, '<b>$<title></b>');`